# Best way to reverse engineer LinkedIn web page?

Tags: reverse-engineering, fiddler

I am building an app that integrates sending e-mail over LinkedIn to your contacts in our CRM and I would like to try and reverse engineer what happens on the LinkedIn e-mail page when you click "Send Message".

I am using Fiddler, but all I see is some massive GUID-like number being sent on the wire when I click "Send Message" on this page. Does anyone have any suggestions about how I could reverse engineer what is going on with the "Send Message" button?

Comment: Integrating your CRM with another site is why there are API's. If what you're trying to do doesn't exist in the API means it's likely the site owner doesn't want their site used in that matter and reverse engineering around that is just wrong, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn doesn't actually send email with that message, it sends LinkedIn messages within the system.  This is supported by our APIs and you're encouraged to use those APIs for this purpose.

The message sending API is documented here:
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/messaging-between-connections-api

There's sample code for using the Javascript API here:
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/sample-code-sending-message